# Covariance Derivation in a 2SLS-setting to Show Small Sample Bias

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares, covariance, instrumental-variables

In their 1999 paper introducing Jackknife instrumental variable estimators, Angrist and Krueger show that $\hat{\beta} _{2SLS}$ is asymptotically unbiased, but for fixed sample sizes the bias increases with the number of instruments $K$.

They formally describe this on page 59 with the following formula:

(1) $E[\epsilon_iZ_i\hat{\pi}]=E[E[\epsilon_iZ_i\hat{\pi}|Z]=E[Z_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z_i'\cdot E[\epsilon_i \eta_i'|Z]]=E[Z_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z_i'\sigma_{\epsilon \eta}']=(K/N)\sigma_{\epsilon \eta}'$,

where:

- $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$
- $X=Z\pi+\eta$
- $Z_i\hat{\pi}=Z_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'X$

and we assume

- $E[\epsilon_i \eta_i'|Z]=\sigma_{\epsilon \eta}$
- $E[\eta|Z]=0$
- $E[\eta_i'\eta|Z]=\Sigma_{\eta}$

I am struggling to connect the second and third equalities in formula (1). Substituting in for $\hat{\pi}$ gives:

(2) $E[E[\epsilon_iZ_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'X|Z]]=E[E[\epsilon_iZ_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'(Z\pi+\eta)|Z]]=E[E[\epsilon_iZ_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'\eta|Z]]$,

because $E[E[\epsilon_iZ_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'Z\pi|Z]]=0$.

How can we show that $E[E[\epsilon_iZ_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z'\eta|Z]]=E[Z_i(Z'Z)^{-1}Z_i'\cdot E[\epsilon_i \eta_i'|Z]]$?

In particular, how do we end up with the subscripts on the final $Z_i'$ and $\eta_i'$?